# Unexpected result after addition

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I'm coding a personal project in Java right now and have recently been using bit operations for the first time. I was trying to convert two bytes into a short, with one byte being the upper 8 bits and the other being the lower 8 bits.

I ran into an error when running the first line of code below.

#### Incorrect Results

```
short regPair = (short) ( (byte1 << 8) + (byte2) );
```

#### Correct Results

```
short regPair = (short) ( (byte1 << 8) + (byte2 & 0xFF) );
```

The expected results were: `AAAAAAAABBBBBBBB`, where `A` represents bits from `byte1` and `B` represents bits from `byte2`.

Using the 1st line of code I would get the typical addition between a bit-shifted byte1 with byte 2 added to it.

#### Example of incorrect results

```
byte1 = 11, byte2 = -72

result = 2816 -72
       = 2744
```

When using the line of code which produces the expected results I can get the proper answer of 3000. I am curious as to why the bit-masking is needed for `byte2`. My thoughts are that it converts `byte2` into binary before the addition and then performs binary addition with both bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the incorrect case, `byte2` is promoted to an `int` because of the `+` operator. This doesn't just mean adding some zeros to the start of the binary representation of `byte2`. Since integer types are represented in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) in Java, **1s** will be added. After the promotion, `byte2` becomes:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 1000
```

By doing `& 0xFF`, you force the promotion to `int` *first*, then you keep the least significant 8 bits: `1011 1000` and make everything else 0.

Answer (score 1):

Print the intermediate value directly to see what is going on. Like,

```
System.out.printf("%d %s%n", ((byte) -72) & 0xFF, Integer.toBinaryString(((byte) -72) & 0xFF));
```

I get

```
184 10111000
```

So the correct code is actually adding 184 (not subtracting 72).

Answer (score 0):

So I totally forgot that `byte` is singed in Java, therefore when performing math with a variable of this data type it will take the signed interpretation and not the direct value of the bits. By performing `byte2 & 0xFF`, Java converts the signed byte value into an unsigned int with all but the first 8 bits set as 0's. Therefore you can perform binary addition correctly.

signed byte value `0x11111111 = -1`

unsigned byte value `0x11111111 = 255`

Comment: You get the unsigned value by doing this but it is not 'converted to an unsigned int'. There are no unsigned ints in Java.

Comment: That's not really correct. Java takes the bits from the byte exactly as they are. Then Java promotes the 8-bit signed byte to a 32-bit signed integer, which means adding 24 ones to the front of the byte since the byte has a negative value. Of you apply `& 0xff` *after* that, then you turn that 32-bit int into a positive value with just the lower-order 8 bits remaining. You should also apply `& 0xff` to byte1 - your saving grace is your cast to `short` which cuts off the highest-order 16 bits as well.

Answer (score 0):

> In both cases byte values are promoted to int in the expression when
>   it is evaluated.

```
byte byte1 = 11, byte2 = -72;
short regPair = (short) ( (byte1 << 8) + (byte2) );
```

(2816) + (-72) = 2744

And even in below expression byte is promoted to int

```
short regPair = (short) ( (byte1 << 8) + (byte2 & 0xFF) );
```

2816 + 184 = 3000

Here in this expression there is no concatenation of two bytes like it has been expressed in the above question- AAAAAAAABBBBBBBB, where A represents bits from byte1 and B represents bits from byte2.

Actually -7 & 255 gives 184 which is added to 2816 to give the output 3000.